# $\sigma$-algebra generated by sequence of subsets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Let $(A_n)_n$ be sequence of subsets of a set $\Omega$. For all $a \in \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$, define

\begin{equation} \label{eu_eqn}
F(a) := \bigcap^\infty_{i=1}A_i^{(a_i)} ,
\end{equation}
where $A^{(0)}:= A_i$ and $A^{(1)}:= A_i^c$.

I have already shown that the collection $\{F(a): a \in \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} \}$ is a partition of $\Omega$. I have also already shown that \begin{equation} 
\sigma((A_n)_n) = \{\bigcup_{a \in J}F(a): J \subset \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} \}.
\end{equation} I have done this by proving that the right hand side is just a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $(A_n)_n$. My goal is now to prove the following statement:

$\sigma((A_n)_n)$ is either finite or uncountable.

Through my construction it is easy to see that $\sigma((A_n)_n)$ is uncountable if it is infinite, since if it is infinite, then $(A_n)_n$ should contain an infinite amount of different elements. In that case, the right hand side has the same cardinality as the set of all sequences in $\{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ (which is uncountable many). I know this because for every $a \in \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ I can define $J:= \{a \}$. However, there is one thing that stands in the way of my proof. In order for it to have that cardinality, I have to show that there is a one-to-one correspondence between every sequence $a \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and the set $\{F(a): a \in \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} \}$. So I first have to prove the following statement:

\begin{equation}
\forall a,b \in \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}: a \neq b \Rightarrow F(a) \neq F(b).
\end{equation}
However, when I try this, I get into all sorts of problems with the empty set. This statement is fairly easy to prove if $F(a)$ or $F(b)$ is not the empty set. However, when I assume $F(a) = \emptyset$, it is not apparent for me to see that $F(b) \neq \emptyset$. In other words, the collection $\{F(a): a \in \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} \}$ is clearly a partition of $\Omega$, but it is not clear for me that more than one $a \in \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ can correspond to the empty set (maybe even an uncountable amount, such that the right hand side could possibly be countable). Note that my definition of partition of a set $\Omega$ is just a collection of disjoint sets such that the (disjoint) union of those sets is $\Omega$ (so the empty set **can** be in the partition). I feel like I'm close to proving the statement, but I am just stuck at this silly little nuance. Or maybe I have made an error of some kind somewhere...

Comment: (Ignore my previous deleted comment. That was incorrect. This is the corrected version.) First of all, the statement that $\sigma((A_n)_n) = \{\bigcup_{a \in J}F(a): J \subset \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} \}$ is not necessarily true. There’s no reason for the $\sigma$-algebra on the LHS to contain all elements on the RHS except those with $J$ being either countable or co-countable (though it certainly can do so as well, there’s just no guarantee). You only have the LHS is included in the RHS and the RHS with $J$ required to be countable or co-countable is included in the LHS.

Comment: And no, there’s no reason why there can’t be multiple elements in $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$ which all have $F$ of that element equaling the empty set. Instead, you should consider directly the cardinality of your partition $K = \{F(a): a \in \{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}\}$ and see that, by the description of $\sigma((A_n)_n)$ above, your $\sigma$-algebra contains a copy of the $\sigma$-algebra of countable and co-countable subsets of $K$. If your $\sigma$-algebra is infinite, then $K$ is infinite, so the $\sigma$-algebra of countable and co-countable subsets of $K$ is uncountable, so is $\sigma((A_n)_n)$.

Comment: I get why we should check what the cardinality of the partition $K$ is, because if $K$ is uncountable we know that $\sigma((A_n)_n)$ is also uncountable because $ K \subset \sigma((A_n)_n)$ but I still do not understand how to do this. I could not follow what you mean after "by the description of..." Also, how do you know that if $\sigma((A_n)_n)$ is infinite, then $K$ is infinite ? The only thing I can conlude out of $\sigma((A_n)_n)$ is infinite, is that the sequence $(A_n)_n$ contains an infinite amount of different elements.

Comment: It is still nog guaranteed that an uncountable amount of $a \in \{ 0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ does not give rise to only the empty set, such that $K$ could still possibly be countable.

Comment: As noted before, $\sigma((A_n)_n) \subseteq \{\bigcup_{a \in J}F(a): J \subseteq \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}\} = \{\bigcup X: X \subseteq K\}$. Thus, if $K$ is finite, then the RHS is finite, then so is $\sigma((A_n)_n)$. So if $\sigma((A_n)_n)$ is infinite, $K$ must be infinite as well.

Comment: More precisely, I should have said $\sigma((A_n)_n)$ contains a copy of the $\sigma$-algebra of countable and co-countable subsets of $K \setminus \{\varnothing\}$ rather than $K$.

Comment: But to simplify this a bit, for any countable subset $X \subseteq K \setminus \{\varnothing\}$, $\bigcup X$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra. Because $K$ is a partition and now I have removed the empty set from the picture, you can now prove that for different $X$, $\bigcup X$ must be different. If $K$ is infinite, then $K \setminus \{\varnothing\}$ is infinite as well, and any infinite set has uncountably many countable subsets.

Comment: An example where $K$ is countable but infinite: if you start with a sequence $(A_n)$ that is already a countably infinite partition of $\Omega$, then your $K$ will actually be countable. For an example where $K$ is uncountable, consider $\Omega = \{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and $A_n$ consists of those elements whose $n$-th coordinate is 0. This is also an example that shows your original description that $\sigma((A_n)_n) = \{\bigcup_{a \in J} F(a): J \subseteq \{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}\}$ is incorrect. The RHS consists of all subsets of $\Omega$, but the LHS is much smaller.

Comment: (In fact, the RHS in the second example is of cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ while the LHS is of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.)

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you confirm that I understand the points you make? 1) So $\sigma((A_n)_n) \subseteq \{\bigcup_{a \in J}F(a): J \subseteq \{0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}\}$ is true because the RHS is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains every $A_n$ (provable). However, the other inclusion does not hold because elements in the RHS can be uncountable unions of elements in $K$, and those are not guaranteed to also be in $\sigma((A_n)_n)$?

Comment: 2) So I don't need to know the exact cardinality of $K$, I just need to know that it is infinite such that $K \setminus \{ \emptyset \}$ is infinite such that I can prove that there are an uncountable amount of countable subsets $X \subset K$ which leads to an uncountable amount of  $\bigcup X$ in $\sigma ((A_n)_n)$ (and these are now provable to be all different because I removed  the empty set, which was a problem for me from the beginning)?

Comment: To both points: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, if $\mathcal{F} := \{F(a): a \in \{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}\}$ is finite, than so is $\Sigma := \sigma((A_n)),$ so your question just asks you to prove that $\Sigma$ is uncountable when $\mathcal{F}$ is infinite. Consider an arbitrary injection $i : \mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{F}.$ This injection gives rise to a natural injection $\mathfrak{i} : 2^\mathbb{N} \to \Sigma$ defined by
$$\mathfrak{i} ((b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} i(n)^{b_n},$$
where $A^0 := \emptyset, \text{ } A^1 := A.$ Indeed, if $(b_n) \neq (b_n'),$ let $m := \min \{n: b_n \neq b_n'\}$ and WLOG, $b_n = 0 = 1 - b_n'.$ Then $i(m) \cap \mathfrak{i} ((b_n')_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) = i(m),$ while $i(m) \cap \mathfrak{i} ((b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) = \emptyset$ since all of the $i(n)'s$ are disjoint. It follows that $\Sigma$ is uncountable. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: How do you know that if $\mathcal{F}$ is finite, then $\Sigma$ is finite ? Also, you considered that there exists an injection $i: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$, but how do you know that ? Doesn't that mean that $\mathcal{F}$ is countable, which we do not want to prove because we want it to be uncountable such that $\Sigma$ is uncountable. I assume you meant to assume this so to get a contradiction, but I don't see any contradiction.

Comment: @Einsteinwasmyfather There’s an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to any infinite set, not just countable ones.

Comment: To answer your first question, if $\mathcal{F}$ is finite, then so is $\Sigma$ since this last set will contain unions of sets in the former set. In fact, its cardinal will be $2^{\# \mathcal{F}}.$ As for the second question, David already answered it and your assumption is wrong, I did not want to get a contradiction, my proof provides you with an injection from $2^\mathbb{N}$ to $\Sigma,$ which proves that it will certainly be uncountable. This proof works irrespective of the exact form of the $\sigma-$algebra, as all of the considered sets must be in it.